# I want to delete certain strings from a text file in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am very new to python.
I have a text file which contains certain strings which I am logging to csv file using pandas.

I want to remove certain strings which starts with specific characters from the file.
Please let me know how can i do it.

The Text file contains the strings something like this

```
 "<S t='a' s='3'/>SetRTEConfig,Done,<S t='s' c='IgnoreCase' s='5'/>{LogUutCurrentVersions}{GetMcbVersion}LogAndReportLastVersion,"v1.22.000",Passed....
```

and so on.. I need to delete all those which starts from `<S t='a'`. I need only those data which starts from `<S t='s'`

Comment: This is too broad/vague. Please see: [ask].

Comment: How's the data stored in the text file?

Comment: The Text file contains the strings something like this     "<S t='a' s='3'/>SetRTEConfig,Done,<S t='s' c='IgnoreCase' s='5'/>{LogUutCurrentVersions}{GetMcbVersion}LogAndReportLastVersion,"v1.22.000",Passed....  and so on.. I need to delete all those which starts from<S t='a'. I need only those data which starts from <S t='s'

Comment: @AkshayShirahatti That should be in your post. Again, this is too broad and vague. What have you tried, exactly?

Comment: I'm sourcing this file and writing to csv using pandas .

Comment: But i have no clue how to strip the parts of string

Answer (score 1):

You can do something along these lines:

```
goodlines = []
with open('textfile.txt','r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line[0:8]=="<S t='s'":
        goodlines.append(line)
```

If you need more advanced pattern matching you can use '[regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)'

Answer (score 1):

Solution using regex:

```
import re
contents = "<S t='a' s='3'/>SetRTEConfig,Done,<S t='s' c='IgnoreCase'" \
           " s='5'/>{LogUutCurrentVersions}{GetMcbVersion}LogAndReportLastVersion,\"v1.22.000\",Passed...."

pattern = re.compile(r'<S t=\'s\'(.*)')
result = pattern.findall(contents)
print(result)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[' c=\'IgnoreCase\' s=\'5\'/>{LogUutCurrentVersions}{GetMcbVersion}LogAndReportLastVersion,"v1.22.000",Passed....']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the python solution here is much better than using a regex, but since you asked for it, you could do something like this for a regex solution:

```
import re
s=''' "<S t='a' s='3'/>SetRTEConfig,Done,<S t='s' c='IgnoreCase' s='5'/>{LogUutCurrentVersions}{GetMcbVersion}LogAndReportLastVersion,"v1.22.000",Passed....'''
re.findall(r"<S t='s'.+?>([^<]+)", s)
['{LogUutCurrentVersions}{GetMcbVersion}LogAndReportLastVersion,"v1.22.000",Passed....']
# assuming you don't want the tag but only the text after it?
```

Or, directly into pandas:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO; import pandas as pd; import re
>>> pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(re.findall(r"<S t='s'.+?>([^<]+)", s))), sep=",")
# this will look off since its falsey data with no header...
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [{LogUutCurrentVersions}{GetMcbVersion}LogAndReportLastVersion, v1.22.000, Passed....]
Index: []
```

However, the above is quite crude -- it won't work for example if there is a "<" in the csv data. To re-iterate: I would use the python example -- it will be much simpler to use and be more flexible when you run into more conditions.

Comment: didn't work out also tried the following script     import pandas as pd
        df = pd.read_csv("large.csv", header= None)
        df.drop(labels="<S t='a'", axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False)
        df.to_csv("automated.csv")